# Скачивание картинки по URL

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Downloader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Downloader dowloader = new Downloader();
        dowloader.downloadFiles("http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a", "C:\\Users\\IP44", 1);
    }

    public static void downloadFiles(String strURL, String strPath, int buffSize)  {
        try {
            URL connection = new URL(strURL);
            HttpURLConnection urlconn;
            urlconn = (HttpURLConnection) connection.openConnection();
            urlconn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlconn.connect();
            InputStream in = null;
            in = urlconn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(strPath);
            byte buffer[] = new byte[buffSize];
            int c = in.read(buffer);
            while (c > 0) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, c);
                c = in.read(buffer);
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Доброго времени суток. Хочу скачать картинку с помощью кода взятого [отсюда](http://www.cyberforum.ru/java-j2se/thread428606.html). Вылетает ошибка: java.io.FileNotFoundException C:\Users\IP44.
Я в свойствах папки java дал себе полные права, а также указывал разные директории. Что можно предпринять?

Comment: файл так и называется `IP44` ? и без расширения?

Comment: Нет, это директория.  Я должен дать название файлу, который скачиваю?

Comment: Конечно. Если, предположим, у вас в директории 100500 файлов, то откуда программа должна знать с каким файлом работать? Нужно дать понять конкретно с чем работать надо

Comment: Да, спасибо. Скинул в директорию пустой jpg, и скачиваемая картинки перезаписала его. Как вы думаете, как можно реализовать скачивание без перезаписывания?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка `java.io.FileNotFoundException` говорит о том, что на диске отсутствует файл в который нужно записывать, либо нет прав на директорию. Судя по вашему коду - не назначен файл. То есть как минимум надо в директории его создать, а в аргументах метода добавить его типа

```
downloadFiles("http://imagehost.ru/icon.jng", "C:\\Users\\IP44\\test.jpg", 1);
```

---

Что делать, если нужно много всяких картинок качать и вручную создавать эти файлы слишком напряжно?

**Во-первых:** `FileOutputStream` в качестве входного параметра может принимать аргумент типа `File`.

Соответственно мы уже можем написать что-то типа такого:

```
File file = new File(strPath + "test.jpg");
OutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

где `test.jpg` - имя файла, которое можно генерировать рандомно или как душа пожелает.

но, это? если мне изменяет память, вызовет ошибку, опять же, если файл предварительно не создан на диске :'( отсюда следует

**Во-вторых:** `File` имеет метод `createNewFile`, который создает файл на диске. То есть проверяем, существует файл на диске, если нет, то создаем. Выглядит это так:

```
if(!file.exists()) {
    //Создаем его.
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

В итоге в методе `downloadFiles` следует вместо строки

```
OutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(strPath);
```

написать

```
String myRandomName = "test.jpg"; // Генерируйте любое удобное имя вместо хардкорного
File file = new File(strPath + myRandomName);

if(!file.exists()) {
    //Создаем его.
    file.createNewFile();
}

OutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Должно работать.

---

**UPD**: говорят в комментах, что ошибка при `new File` будет, только если файл нельзя открыть для записи, вызывать `createNewFile` не обязательно.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробный ответ.

Comment: "это вызовет ошибку, опять же, если файл предварительно не создан на диске" - ошибка будет, только если файл нельзя открыть для записи, вызывать `createNewFile` не обязательно

Comment: @zRrr точно? ммм. дополню ниже...

Comment: @Kojer Defor - говорят, createNewFile не обязательно))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я проверил. `createNewFile` можно пользоваться, если хочется вместо ловли исключения проверить возвращаемое значение. Еще с семерки есть `Files.newOutputStream` с возможностью указания параметров открытия файла.